# xpath to fetch any gadget of category value "Tourism", and any sibling before gadget[1]

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml structure of the form;

```
<Gadgets>              <!--This is the root node-->                          

<info>                
    <author>Yours sincerely</author>
    <email>me@yahoo.com</email>         
    <phone>+23407------</phone>
    <website>me.com</website>
</info>

<!-- I want info and any node before here selected--> 

<gadget>
    -------
</gadget>   

<gadget>
    <title>News</title>
    <link>blalblala.php</link>
    <description>contains News</description>
    <category>Tourism</category>
    <image url="image2.jpj" title="image name" link="location.jpg"/>
    <comment>link to image comments</comment>
    <enclosure url="blaaaa.jpg" length="something" type="imag"/>
</gadget>

<gadget>
```

using xpath, i want to select info (or any node before gadget[1]) and any gadget where category has a value of Tourism. currently, this is what i have:

```
"./*/gadget[category = 'Tourism']/following-sibling::gadget[1]"
```

i also tried this:

```
"./*/gadget[category = 'Tourism' or following-sibling::gadget[1]]"
```

and

"Gadgets/*[self::gadget and category = 'Tourism' or (self::following-sibling::gadget)]"

None is selecting info as expected. any guide will be highly appreciated. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//gadget[./category/text()='Tourism'] | //gadget[1]/preceding-sibling::*
```

Or if you want only one "any node" closest to first `gadget` use

```
//gadget[./category/text()='Tourism'] | //gadget[1]/preceding-sibling::*[1]
```